# Splash screen is really Useful? Can we use any other Innovative Concept ? Is it really best practice?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, io, splash-screen

For some unfathomable reason Google decided to add Splash Screens (Launch Screen) to their design guidelines, I know that,

**1. Splash screen is better than staring at an empty screen.**

................ [ Inflating the main layout and showing a UI without any dynamic data should be very fast. If that's not the case in your app you should fix it by making it fast to load instead of adding a splash screen that will then guarantee that your app is always launching slow.]

**2. Splash screen is better than not having any information if the app is launching other than the launcher button getting pressed.**

**3.app's data takes a long time to load. A splash screen is better than a loading indicator. This especially with slow internet speeds.**

**All these problems , But splash Screen Is not only Single solution I think, It also have some Cons Like:**

1. If you show your app's UI to the user first and then load the data into it you allow user to orient to the UI and they're immediately ready to go when the data comes in.
2. Users don't always want to interact with the data on the app's landing screen. Let the user get on with their task without forcing them to load the first screen's data. This is very important especially on a slow internet connection. Let user interact with your app while the data is loading. In many cases they might not care about the data you're loading by default.

********** Friends,**I am using **UBER App** & even only I want to see my **"Promo code"** To share with friend I need to Open app & Its take lots of time to open and for that much time I stuck on Splash screen & If there is no internet connection then app Stuck on startup I can't even read my **"Promo Code"**

So, My question is that , **can we avoid splash screen there is another alternative?** **Its really needed & useful?** **Why cant we think about any other innovative Concept?**

Comment: If the data which is being loaded in splash screen is essential to move to further screens, then I don't think that there is any other option other than splash screen.

Comment: but, Users don't always want to interact with the data on the app's landing screen, sometime user interested only in static data[ eg. Uber App]

Comment: Then you can move the data fetching code to a background thread and let the user navigate to next screen.

Comment: Ya that's the the thing I'm talking about

Comment: But what happens if user navigates to the screen where the fetched data is used before the fetching is complete??

Comment: It at least allow user to orient to the UI and user can interact with static data , I know for that somehow we need to change app structure

Comment: Yes. You have to change it then

Answer (score 1):

Splash screens also allow for the app itself to load. some apps like facebook are not actually apps but the normal website for mobile phones... made into its own special browser for only that website. thus, the app itself must load even its menus, which have icons and all on them. splash screens definitely would be great for those apps, though, other apps such as a non-website app..IE, something that loads locally then connects to the internet to update and cache data would totally be usable without a splash screen. you could straight up display or open the app to a menu and show a loading wheel on the menu options that aren't fully loaded yet. instead of a splash screen, you could also show terms and conditions of your app so users can go ahead and agree to them if they are required (such as apps that require use of an online service.)

Comment: Thanks, You are right , I know that splash screen is necessary, but now days to increase the efficiency of app we have to come up with some innovative idea as I mention in Q. like terms & Cond. but some useful task

Comment: to be honest, it depends on the app. some apps, when loading first time, show a tutorial of the app itself, having the user tap to learn how to use the app. the splash screen could litterally be an animation telling the user how to use the app, instead of a static logo. this would be more efficient to show the user how to use it. chat apps and games do this. another thing chat apps do, is on first time loading, they ask a quesetionaire to get the user all set up in using ther service before even loading the menus.

Comment: don't forget to select an answer if this was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just display a dialog about you app updates or If ur app contains login functionality just use login using dialog.I think it may be an best alternative for splash.